# Not able to see Location in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, profile-page, data-explorer, users

I am using the following query in Stack Exchange Data Explorer:

```
SELECT Id, DisplayName, Reputation, Location
FROM users 
WHERE Id = '3628106'
ORDER BY Reputation DESC
```

But I don't see *Location* in the result:

[image]

But [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3628106/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A3) has *Location* in the profile:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Comment: Data on SEDE is week old. Have you set up location recently?